# Database Agnostic Conditional

Tags: mysql, postgresql, query

I'm writing a Drupal module and I want it to be agnostic between PostgreSQL and MySQL. I have a field that gets its value from a conditional, and I originally wrote it as an `IF()`. Then I found out that `IF()` is a MySQL-ism. So, I looked up the conditionals for PostgreSQL and `CASE` seemed to be the best tool.

However, I noticed that [`CASE` ends with `END` in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-conditional.html), while in [MySQL it ends with `END CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html). Will this destroy my hopes for database agnosticism? Can I write an agnostic query with a conditional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using CASE expressions in a SELECT statement, you should be looking at [this page in the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html).  As shown there, you use `END` to end a CASE expression.

If, on the other hand, you're using CASE as part of a flow control statement (like you might use in a stored procedure to conditionally execute other statements), both databases would use `END CASE` to end a CASE statement.

Comment: OK, but now your question is a bit confused, because the MySQL CASE expression ends with `END`, not `END CASE`.

Comment: I'll be darned! Everything is okay then :)

Comment: @dmd - you said: "it sounds like the syntax differs between the two databases". Actually they [are the same](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN50027) for the the `case` statement as well

Comment: @Jack Douglas: Ah, very good!  I'll edit my answer to remove that bit of inaccuracy.  Thanks.

Comment: For the benefit of all (including myself) : CASE WHEN END works as an independent SELECT, while CASE WHEN END CASE; works in a Stored Procedure. While my answer was DB agnostic and errs on the side of caution, dmc is clearly and contextually correct. Bravo, dmc. I already gave +1 to your answer !!!

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Function Syntax between MySQL and PostgreSQL will never converge as you wish UNLESS you are willing to take a chance on some weird way to emulate the IF() function in a convoluted manner:

**WRITE A STORED FUNCTION !!!**

The IF conditional function could be called MyIF and do the following:

- you could pass the necessary parameters to MyIF
- define whatever CASE structure or stored procedure logic you want
- you will have to define the MyIF stored function in MySQL and PostgreSQL

Hence, the query can be appear to be agnostic when calling the MyIF Function.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: +1, that's what stored procedures are there for. Plus it will help with other statements also.